# Redirecting from PHP-based web servers to ELB and tomcat applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elb, ajp

I have an `AWS` deployment where I have a web-server (serving a PHP-based website) and an application server (serving `JSP/Tomcat` based applications). The redirection from the webserver to the application server is made via `AJP` over port 8009. This is specified in `workers.properties`.

This works well when there is only one application server whose private IP is specified in the `host` directive of `workers.properties`.

This redirection fails the moment the application server is placed behind an `ELB`. The redirection from PHP to Tomcat fails. What I have tried so far:

1. Specified the `ELB` endpoint in the `workers.properties` file.
2. Changed all `JkMount` directives in the `virtualhost.conf` file to `ProxyPass` directives. The following is the change:
   `JkMount /application* tomcat1`
   to
   `ProxyPass /application ajp://ELBDNSName:8009/application`

This too does not work.

How do I get the redirection to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing things a lot:

- This is not a redirection, it is a reverse proxy situation.
- AJP is a protocol.

You probably created the ELB in HTTP mode, which means that it tries to talk HTTP both to the clients and the upstreams. Terribly fails since you told them both to talk AJP. Leaving the thing with ProxyPass and switching the ELB to TCP *SHOULD* make things work.

I highly recommend you to go on and start learning or hire an expert.